# Arithmetic operation on selective rows in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R, so this question may seem stupid, but please bear with me. Here's what my data looks like:

```
  col1 col2
1     2    9
2     2    2
3     1    8
4     1    1
5     2    4
6     2    5
7     2    3
8     1   10
9     1    6
10    2    7
```

reproducible from

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE),
               col2 = as.factor(sample(10)))
```

I want to have all rows in col2 multiplied by 2, if the corresponding value in col1 is "1". So the end result should be like:

```
  col1 col2
1     2    9
2     2    2
3     1    16
4     1    2
5     2    4
6     2    5
7     2    3
8     1    20
9     1    12
10    2    7
```

And ideas? Appreciation in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If the data were numeric, you could assign to a slice with a simple computation:

```
> d[d$col1==1,2] <- 2*d[d$col1==1,2]
> d
   col1 col2
1     2    9
2     2    2
3     1   16
4     1    2
5     2    4
6     2    5
7     2    3
8     1   20
9     1   12
10    2    7
```

With a factor, this becomes problematic as you cannot do the substitution in-place (the existing factor doesn't have the appropriate levels).  Instead, you must create a new factor with the desired levels:

```
d$col2 <- as.factor(ifelse(d$col1==1, 2*as.numeric(d$col2), d$col2))
```

Comment: with the data provided by the OP I do not think this works because `col2` is a factor. A conversion to numeric is required I think.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the columns are `numeric`

```
 transform(df1, col2= (2+(col1==1)-1)*col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
data$col2 <- as.numeric(data$col2) * (1 + (data$col1==1))
```